# How can I change icons color in button?

Tags: android, button, colors, icons

I created button with text and icon:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkToProfile"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/profile"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/profile"/>
```

And I want to set icon color, how to do this in `<Button/>` tag or it can be set only in `<ImageView/>` tag?

Comment: See : [how to change color of compounddrawable on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926123/how-to-change-color-of-compounddrawable-on-button)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change android button drawable icon color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714018/change-android-button-drawable-icon-color-programmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the  android:drawableTint="#000000" for the drawable like

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLinkToProfile"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/profile"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:textSize="15dp" 
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/profile"
    android:drawableTint="#000000"
    android:drawableTintMode="src_in"/>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

`app:iconTint="yourColor"` works for MaterialButton

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ImageButton and set the colour with

```
android:tint="@color/myColour"
```

Comment: and how about text with ImageButton?

Comment: this solution worked for me when i was trying to customize the chromecast mini controller button to white. I had a white icon but it kept appearing as black.